# sharepoint custom list for question and answers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have a list in sharepoint 2010. Basically this is like a question and answer session. But this list is a place where employees can ask question and get the response.
it works like this
Q. What is sharepoint? Once they ask this question, this question should be send as a email to me and only after i reply as answer that should be published in sharepoint until then that question should not be shown in sharepoint. Basically it waits until i reply to that question. Can that be possible in sharepoint 2010.
Please help i am in need of it.

Thanks
Mohammed

Answer (score 1):

In list settings, set the list to require content approval and only allow users without approval rights to read approved items.

You would use a SharePoint Designer workflow when a new item is created to email you the question, then wait until the Answer field is not empty. Then it should set `Content Approval Status` to approved.